# changing only alpha unknown color

Tags: css

I have few classes:

```
.overlay-blue {background-color: rgba(0,123,238,0.9);}
.overlay-orange { background-color:rgba(240,116,7,0.9); }
.overlay-purple { background-color:rgba(126,64,228,0.9); }
.overlay-green { background-color:rgba(57,151,95,0.9) }
.overlay-pink { background-color:rgba(173,33,106,0.9); }
.overlay-light-blue {background-color:rgba(0,183,168,0.9) }
.overlay-red {background-color:rgba(235,50,89,0.9); }


.overlay:hover
{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInFromNone;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
    0% {display:block; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);}
    1% {display: block ; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.89);}
    100% {display: none ; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
}
```

`

this function of hovering is working well but it turns the overlay to black when starging the animation because of the line

```
0% {display:block; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);}
```

which makes sense.

is there a way to dim the alpha channel without duplicating the code for each color?

Comment: If you're familiar with CSS pre-processing language, you can check my updated answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way going about your current approach, because it is impossible to target just the alpha channel in the `rgba()` property separately and change it. What you can do, however, is instead of setting a background colour on your element, set the background colour of a pseudo-element stretched to the full dimension of its parent, and only declare the `rgb()` values. The alpha channel changes can be delegated to the `opacity` property instead. I call this the pseudo-element approach:

## Pseudo-element approach

```
/* Define BG colours of pseudo element instead */
.overlay-blue::before { background-color: rgb(0,123,238);}
.overlay-orange::before { background-color:rgb(240,116,7); }
/* and more... */

/* Set relative positioning of parent element */
.overlay {
    position: relative;
}

/* Stretch pseudo element, declare empty content so it will show */
.overlay::before {
    content: '';
    opacity: .9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* Change opacity when parent element is hovered upon */
.overlay:hover::before {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Of course this is a rather basic implementation of your question ([see demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/rtaw4kxs/)), because I do not know the exact details you want to achieve with your animation keyframes. The good thing is that pseudo-elements can also be animated :)

## SASS approach

**Even better:** Alternatively, you might want to consider using a CSS preprocessor (SCSS, LESS) so that you can use variables, and do not have to repetitively redeclare the background colours. [See the demo here](http://sassmeister.com/gist/5b1abbf1ee3bf2575262).

You can use the following mixin:

```
/* Declare mixin */
@mixin overlayColor($color) {
    background-color: rgba($color, 0.9);
    &:hover { background-color: rgba($color, 0.3); }
}

/* Use @include for each colour class, you only have to declare the rgb(a) values */
.overlay {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;

    &.overlay-blue {
        @include overlayColor(rgb(0,123,238));
    }
    &.overlay-orange {
        @include overlayColor(rgb(240,116,7));
    }
    /* and more... */
}
```